# Combine multiple methods

Tags: c#

I have two functions, One for getting random Word from `CSV` file that contains an specific String, And One for getting word that Not Contains specific String,

What i want now, is to get random word that Contains say "A" and Not Contains "D",
is there a way to use these two methods somehow to achieve this goal without rewriting a new method?

**I should mention, that these use cases are just two examples, i have many other functions that i may need to combine them (getting a word with specific Length, getting a word with starting character and...). so i'm looking for a general solution.**

`GetRandomWordContaining` Function:

```
public static string GetRandomWordContainig(string word)
{
    Debug.Log(word);
    TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Words");

    string[] data = textAsset.text.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

    string result = "NULL";
    int randomMiddle = UnityEngine.Random.Range(5, data.Length);


    for (int i = randomMiddle; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = data[i].TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
        data[i] = data[i].TrimStart('\r', '\n');
        bool isAns = true;
        for(int j = 0; j < word.Length; j++)
        {
            if (!data[i].Contains(word[j].ToString()))
            {
                isAns = false;
            }
        }
        if (isAns) return data[i];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < randomMiddle; i++)
    {
        data[i] = data[i].TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
        data[i] = data[i].TrimStart('\r', '\n');
        bool isAns = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < word.Length; j++)
        {
            if (!data[i].Contains(word[j].ToString()))
            {
                isAns = false;
            }
        }
        if (isAns) return data[i];
    }

    return result;

}
```

`GetRandomWordNotContainig` Function:

```
public static string GetRandomWordNotContaining(string s)
{
    TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Words");

    string[] data = textAsset.text.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

    string result = "NULL";

    int randomMiddle = UnityEngine.Random.Range(5, data.Length);

    for (int i = randomMiddle; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = data[i].TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
        data[i] = data[i].TrimStart('\r', '\n');
        bool isOk = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
        {
            if (data[i].Contains(s[j].ToString()))
            {
                isOk = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isOk) result =  data[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < randomMiddle; i++)
    {
        data[i] = data[i].TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
        data[i] = data[i].TrimStart('\r', '\n');
        bool isOk = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
        {
            if (data[i].Contains(s[j].ToString()))
            {
                isOk = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isOk) result =  data[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your existing methods [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for `string` class like below.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string GetRandomWordContainig(this string s, string include)
    {
        // your method body.
        return s + yourResult;
    }

    public static string GetRandomWordNotContaining(this string s, string exclude)
    {
        // your method body.
        return s + yourResult;
    }

    // Add other extension methods that modify length, etc. and chain them.
}
```

Now use it like:

```
var randomString = string.Empty
                         .GetRandomWordContainig("include")
                         .GetRandomWordNotContaining("exclude");
```

You might also want to check out [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) with a fluent interface. This is a more object-oriented approach and will give you better control on what to do if the same word is requested to be included as well as excluded.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing such a builder pattern with a fluent interface - would you have time to elaborate a bit on that?  It sounds useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you even need the second function for this use case.

```
    string include = "A";
    string exclude = "D";

    string candidate = GetRandomWordContainig(include);

    while (candidate.Contains(exclude)){
      GetRandomWordContainig(include);
    }

    return candidate;
```

Comment: thank you @Mathew Evans, but i'm not looking for a solution to solve this specific use case, i updated my question. i'm looking for a general solution for combining methods.

Comment: Sure - then @swdon has proposed extension methods which will work well